# Check if a new row is added to a DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I download data from my server and use a `DataGridView` to present the result. When a new row is added, I’d like my program to show a signal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the `DataGridView.RowsAdded` event.

```
dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowsAdded);

void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    // show the signal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use userAddedRow event , when activate that event you can use it to send
 boolean like true or false like this Example

```
 private void usersDGV_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
     //this event occurs when user added new row to the datagridview 
     //and will turn the boolean newRowAdded on.
           newRowAdded = true;
  }
```